# Folder turned into OneNote file

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, onenote

I have a folder containing a number of files.

Someone has converted that into a OneNote file - I don't know how.

If I open the folder via the web browser I am taken to OneNote online - a blank workbook, and the original folder's files are inaccessible.

I am able to access the folder's files via File Explorer.

Is there a way to convert the OneNote file back into a normal folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone tried creating One note at the same sharepoint folder location. Since folder already existed, it converted existing folder to One Note. Each subfolder got created as a section.
There is no way to convert it back to normal folder. If you browse the library in explorer, you can see files under each folder. Copy files using explorer view and move it to a new folder.